# explanation of dot notation on class.property

Tags: python, class, oop, properties

I'm trying to understand deeply why use a same name of variable in a class property? The code below:

```
    class Cat:
      def __init__ (self, color, legs)
        self.color = color
        self.legs = legs

    felix = Cat("black, 4)
```

I can write it as this:

```
    class Cat:
      def __init__ (self, color, legs)
       self.classColor = color
       self.classLegs = legs

    felix = Cat("black", 4)
```

or this:

```
   class Cat:
      def __init__ (self, catColor, catLegs)
       self.color = catColor
       self.legs = catLegs

   felix = Cat("black", 4)
```

I see the first one as the conventional way of declaring properties of class and variables. Found some information on internet they write it that way as to avoid confusion but I'm confused why is not having an error?

Comment: `some_name` is distinct from `some_object.some_name`. In fact, the two variables live in separate *namespaces*.

Comment: Also, important to note, Python does *not have variable declarations*.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what constitutes "proof" in this regard. You can start by reading [a little about the python execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding). If you prefer something a little bit more empirical, then play around with introspecting `locals()` and `vars(self)` to see the two separate namespaces. Note, `locals()` will return a `dict` object, and while many Python namespaces are indeed `dict` objects, local namespaces are optimized and local variables lookups are optimized to a symbol-table lookup by the compiler